# how can I import a file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have developed a node.js application and performing some validation with the use of a template. At the moment this 'template' is a local variable but I would like to store this in a file in my project. So this is the validation code:

```
isvalid(req.body,template
   , function(err, validObj) {
        if (!validObj) {
           validJson = false;
        }
});
```

the template variable looks like this:

```
var template={
       type: Object,
       "schema":
       {
          "totalRecords": {type:Number},
          "skip": {type:Number},
          "take": {type:Number}
       }
}
```

Suppose I have a file which contains the template contents how can I import this into my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change this line:

```
var template={
```

to this:

```
module.exports={
```

And then you can simply do:

```
var template = require('./path/to/template.js');
```

Note that this is a *relative* path to your file.

You need to set `module.exports` because that is the convention NodeJS uses to say "this is what will be returned if you `require()` this file.

Answer (score 1):

```
var template = require('./template.json');
```

except that `type: Object` would need to be `"type": "Object"` (as a string), to conform to JSON standard (and, of course, without `var template =`, as Felix Kling correctly notes). If you actually want the `Number` etc. objects that actually exist in the JS object space, you would need to make it a proper Node module; require syntax stays the same.